# Starting a navigation view at a certain XIB

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a navigation view controller with XIB file and a scroll view in it. 
How can I make it load a certain file first (that I'll choose)?

Comment: I think you should give an example of what you've done and show some of the code. Have you looked around for your answer first? Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add more details of what you have done till now, and what things you are looking for.